# Hide HTML elements without javascript, only CSS

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, show-hide

I have an html document with many elements like this

```
<article class=slide id=s4>
<h1></h1>

<p></p>
</article>
```

All I want to do is when the link becomes `www.mylink.com#s4` then only the article with `id=s4` to be appeared. And the other to dissapear. I know about the `display:none;` property-value but I dont know how to switch this value without javascript.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9):

In (IE < 9 ∉ modern browsers), you can use the `:target` pseudo-class:

```
section {
    display: none;
}
section:target {
    display: block;
}
```

This pseudo-class matches the element that is referenced in the URL fragment.

For non-browsers, you can use [conditional comment classes](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) to show all of the sections and a warning message:

```
.lt-ie9 section {
    display: block;
}
.ie-warning {
    display: none;
}
.lt-ie9 .ie-warning {
    display: block;
}
```

(or just use Javascript)

Comment: I think I will use Chrome...so, with only these 2 rules I will have the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely want to use the `:target` pseudo class selector.  Check out [this page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/) from css-tricks.  It also includes a way to do this without `:target` so that it works in IE7+ (if that's important to you).

Answer (score -1):

You first need to set your CSS like so:

```
article { display:none; }
```

And then have this JavaScript:

```
var id = document.location.hash.replace('#','');

if(document.location.hash != ''){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Just remember, users without JavaScript turned on won't see anything at all!