# Different CSS Styles for 10 List <li> items

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

What i have here is this:

```
<ul class="bwp-rc-ulist">

<li class="recent-comment">Item 1</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 2</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 3</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 4</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 5</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 6</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 7</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 8</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 9</li>
<li class="recent-comment">Item 10</li>

</ul>
```

I want to add the following CSS styles:

```
li.list1, li.list6 { background-color: red; }
li.list2, li.list7 { background-color: blue; }
li.list3, li.list8 { background-color: black; }
li.list4, li.list9 { background-color: yellow; }
li.list5, li.list10 { background-color: gray; }
```

unfortunately, i cannot do that because the UL & LI is dynamically created by a wordpress plugin (Better Wordpress Comment & Except Plugin).

I've already read some nth-child thingy but it doesn't solve my case. maybe if someone can show me what the correct scripts?

I'm also looking for a script that works in IE7-9, chrome and ff.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why wouldn't nth-child work? That seems like the most appropriate solution for this.

Comment: @Anthony: "The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier." - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp EDIT: here's a IE7/8 solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulEle"  class="bwp-rc-ulist">
    <li class="recent-comment">Item 1</li>
    <li class="recent-comment">Item 2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

OR:

```
<div  id="ulEle">
    <ul  class="bwp-rc-ulist">
        <li class="recent-comment">Item 1</li>
        <li class="recent-comment">Item 2</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ulGet=document.getElementById("ulEle");
  var liList=ulGet.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for(var i=0;i<liList.length;i++)
  {
      liList[i].style.className="list"+(parseInt(i)+1);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: wow! Snger, thank you for your help!

about the line:

<ul id="ulEle"  class="bwp-rc-ulist">

i can't edit the attributes of ul since it's generated dynamically by a plugin. is it possible if you can provide me a code that calls it's ID "bwp-rc-ulist"? is that possible?

Comment: ...is it possible if you can provide me a code that calls it's CLASS NAME "bwp-rc-ulist? instead of using getElementById("ulEle");?

Comment: disregard my last question, i found a way how can i insert that ID="ulEle" to be aligned with your codes. thank you very much! 

i really want to vote for your answer but unfortunately i'm still a newbie here and i don't have that priviledge yet. All i can do is accept your correct answer.

Comment: :> [How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript) [How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

**CSS solution**

```
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(1),
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: red;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(2),
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: blue;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(3),
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(8) {
    background-color: black;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(4),
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(9) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5),
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(10) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

​
or if you prefer it a bit more compact:

```
ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background-color: red;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5n+2) {
    background-color: blue;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5n+3) {
    background-color: black;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5n+4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul.bwp-rc-ulist li:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**jQuery solution (with your CSS)**

```
$('ul.bwp-rc-ulist li.recent-comment').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("list" + (index + 1));
});​
```

Comment: Hi Yannis, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it's not compatible in IE7 and IE8. BUt thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate the effort! :)

Comment: @ScarletAriadneVela That's why I added the jQuery solution ;) [Snger's Javascript solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12345291/99456) should also work in IE7/8. _Don't_ use my jQuery script if you are not already using jQuery, it would be an overkill to load the library just for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this css

http://jsfiddle.net/hVspz/

```
li:nth-child(6n+1) {  
  color: red; 
}

li:nth-child(6n+2) {  
  color: blue;
}
```

and so on

Comment: Couple of small mistakes, it should be `5n+1`, and it's the `background-color` we are trying to set.

Comment: ya ofcourse. I was just trying to suggest a way instead of feeding the exact solution :)