# How to interpret css into jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using this css. But as IE7 and IE8 do not support `nth child` so I want to do it with jQuery so it work in all browser

```
#localFileCopyingDiv, #supplementaryMaterialsDiv, #assetsDiv, table tr td:nth-child(1  /*this is the column number*/){
    text-align: center;
    width:30px
}

#localFileCopyingDiv, #supplementaryMaterialsDiv, #assetsDiv, table tr td:nth-child(2 /*this is the column number*/){ 
    width:250px
}

#localFileCopyingDiv, #supplementaryMaterialsDiv, #assetsDiv, table tr td:nth-child(3 /*this is the column number*/){ 
    width:250px
}

#localFileCopyingDiv, #supplementaryMaterialsDiv, #assetsDiv, table tr td:nth-child(4 /*this is the column number*/){ 
    width:60px
}

#localFileCopyingDiv #supplementaryMaterialsDiv, #assetsDiv  table tr td:nth-child(5 /*this is the column number*/){ 
    width:220px
}

#courseInfoDiv table tr td:nth-child(1 /*this is the column number*/){  
    width: 200px;
}

#courseInfoDiv table tr td:nth-child(2 /*this is the column number*/){  
    width: 600px;
}
```

How can I convert above css into jQuery?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
**--------------------------------------------**

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Status Report</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="brands/default/en/css/exportComplete.css" /></noscript>
    <![endif]--> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="brands/default/en/css/exportComplete.css" />
</head>
```

Is it ok?

Comment: Do you add some of the content affecfted by the css's rules dynamically?

Comment: You could consider this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before

Comment: www.jquery.com read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a plugin such as [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/) to get the `:nth-child` selector (amongst various other pseudo/attribute selectors) functioning in older versions of IE.

> "Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8."

As you're already using a JavaScript library (jQuery), all you need to do is include the Selectivizr `<script>` in your `<head>` and voila.

[**Here's a tutorial**](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/08/start-using-css3-pseudo-classes-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8-using-the-selectivizr-javascript-library/) where you can see a simple example of its use, and an explanation of how it actually works under the cover.

Comment: yes i am including jquery into my HTML like `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: check my edit, is it ok ? that's it or do i need to do something with my css too ?

Comment: @Basit You'll need to change [fallback css] to a .css file. I've added a link you may find useful :)

Comment: Thanks alot. One thing that i need to ask is, i need to include my css after the script right? But what about `<noscript>` tag. The css in this tag can contain css3 selectors or not?

Comment: @Basit Yeah, include the .CSS file after. The <noscript> shouldn't contain CSS3, it is for if the user has JavaScript disabled