# Re-write a Javascript function that selects active navigation tabs to work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have inherited some code in a recent project that makes use of some CSS3 selectors to add classes to some top level tab navigation. Due to the way this has been implemented on the back-end, the JS is searching the window.location.pathname to match a string, and then using that in another function to add the classname in the DOM. This second function is using nth-child(x) where x is a loop that corresponds to the appropriate matching string in the pathname and li. However, as you know, nth-child is not supported in IE8.

I was going to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492882/1636704) style of emulating nth-child in IE8, but I am unclear how to write the function to actually add this into the existing code.

Here is the JS code I am referencing:

```
var tabName = 'Product', tabType = window.location.pathname;
    if(tabType.indexOf('Product')>-1) tabName = 'Product'; 
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Business')>-1) tabName = 'Business'; 
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Support')>-1) tabName = 'Support';
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Article')>-1) tabName = 'Article';

$('.category-tabs li').removeClass('active');
for( var tn = 1; tn < $('.category-tabs li').length+1; tn ++ ){
    if($('.category-tabs li:nth-child(' + tn + ') a').html().indexOf(tabName)>-1){
        $('.category-tabs li:nth-child(' + tn + ')').addClass('active');
    } 
}
```

I would like to add a function that uses this loop, but then also sets it equal to a "li" so that I can use the li:first-child + li method of emulating nth-child, but I could really use some help in making this work.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use CSS class names that correspond with the tab names and access them directly, instead of by index?

Comment: try selectivizr => http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: Diodeus, this is done dynamically. The application uses ATG, so the names of the tabs are fully customizable, even to the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are already using jQuery consider solving the problem with it. Just use *.eq* method to get an access to the specific item in the list. For example:

```
var tabName = 'Product', tabType = window.location.pathname;
    if(tabType.indexOf('Product')>-1) tabName = 'Product'; 
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Business')>-1) tabName = 'Business'; 
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Support')>-1) tabName = 'Support';
    else if(tabType.indexOf('Article')>-1) tabName = 'Article';

var liTags = $('.category-tabs li');
liTags.removeClass('active');
for( var tn = 1; tn < liTags.length+1; tn ++ ){
    var li = liTags.eq(i);
    if(li.find('a').html().indexOf(tabName)>-1){
        li.addClass('active');
    } 
}
```

And try to cache the jQuery selections. It's just much cleaner and readable.

Comment: Look at the original post: "$('.category-tabs li')" -- that *is* jQuery.

Comment: Exactly. I think that because he is already using jQuery he may use it for solving the problem and avoid the usage of css fancy selectors.

Comment: Krasimir, this worked for every nav tab except the first one (once I changed the integer "i" to the "tn"). Strangely enough, I am getting an undefined error on the line:
     

if(li.find('a').html().indexOf(tabName)>-1){

Any clue why I am getting this, and why it is not working on the first nav tab?

Comment: I guess it is because the loop starts from 1. What is the result if you change it to *for( var tn = 0; tn < liTags.length; tn ++ ){*

Comment: Krasimir, that worked great. I guess I should have known, but thanks for all the help.