# Apply css on specific nth-child on IE 7 & 8

Tags: html, css

I am working on a payment form that doesn't support inline style or any other modification inside on it. So i need style it with it nth-child.
Check live- http://uposonghar.com/check/

I successfully create css of it * working fine on Chrome, Safari, Firefox & IE9. But due to using css3 it doesn't work on IE 7 & 8.

Any idea how to apply same style that work on IE 7 & 8.

My css that need to apply on IE 7 & 8-

```
<style>
#frmPayment tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1){
    display:none;
}
#frmPayment tr:nth-child(14) td:nth-child(1){
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you not give your tr and td classnames?

Comment: use jquery/javascript for older version ie

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 :nth-child and :before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before)

Comment: There are no class/id on tr & td. Also no way to add because form is not editable. I am just able to apply style by form id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in using plugins then

[selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.